# Get value of selected dropdown after method "post" in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

im trying to get the value of a selected dropdown my code looks like this:

```
 echo "<form action='trylog.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<div class='custom-select'>";
    echo "<select name='gymnasier'>";

foreach($schools as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "<option>";
    echo "$x"; 
    echo "</option>";

}
echo "<br></option></select>";
echo "<input type='text' id='lectioid' name='lectioid' placeholder='Dit Lectio ID'>";
echo "<input type='submit'>";
echo "</div></form>"
```

So what this does is get the name of "gymnasier" which in this case is the highschool name, however what i want to get is: "$x_value".
But i would like to make people choose the name in the dropdown and i will receive the ID after method "post", in my other php file "trylog.php", instead of the highschool name. "$x".

Comment: Add `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks alot mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `option` tag can have `value` attribute, which is paased to server:

```
echo "<select name='gymnasier'>";

foreach($schools as $x => $x_value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $x . '">';
    echo $x_value; 
    echo "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";    // `<br></option>` is useless
```